# Strange CSS position right:0 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that works for the most part. However not always. I have fiddled with it quite a lot to try get it working with no avail. the issue seems to be intermittent however it definitely reproducible.

What this code tries to do is reposition the `.menu` div to the right or left of the item depending on where in the viewport it is. If the item's right edge is past the halfway mark it changes the side of the `.menu` div.

However, after re-positioning the window a few times and selecting an item that is on the right side it seems that sometimes the CSS doesn't work immediately and it positions the element on the left.

Is my code doing something wrong or has someone else seen this issue before? Does anyone know how to fix it? You can see, by the console values, that right is greater than the width, however, the element is still positioned wrong.

I also checked with an `alert()` and it's definitely going into the `if` at the right point...

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".item", function(event) {
    var widthCenter = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var rightPos = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().right;
    console.log("width center:", widthCenter);
    console.log("right", rightPos);

    if (rightPos > widthCenter)
      $(this).children(".menu").css("right", "0", "!important");
    else
      $(this).children(".menu").css("left", "0", "!important");

    var showingMenu = false;
    if ($(this).children(".menu").is(':visible'))
      showingMenu = true;
    $(".menu").hide();
    if (showingMenu)
      $(this).children(".menu").hide();
    else
      $(this).children(".menu").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 20px;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly fine for me (if the `item` is over halfway from the left, it flips the blue box around).

Comment: keep resizing the window i can assure you it doesn't always work... I'm running Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) however it also did the same with firefox

Comment: It does take a couple of resizes and always choosing an element on the right side

Comment: Perhaps not the answer you are looking for, but if you are also loading jQuery UI along with jQuery, you can use their excellent [position utility](http://jqueryui.com/position/). It has a collision detection mechanism and can be configured to flip the position on other side if needed

Comment: Thanks dogoku i might check it out however i'd prefer to get this working first. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not removing the css, so after a couple of show/close/resize/show iterations, it has both `left:0!important` and `right:0!important` so (I guess) it picks one as the most important, probably the first that was applied.

You can get around this by adding/removing classes rather than manipulating the css directly (it's reasier to remove a class):

add some css:

```
.left { left:0!important }
.right { right:0!important }
```

and toggle the classes:

```
    if (rightPos > widthCenter)
      $(this).children(".menu").addClass("right").removeClass("left");
    else
      $(this).children(".menu").addClass("left").removeClass("right");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".item", function(event) {
    var widthCenter = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var rightPos = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().right;
    console.log("width center:", widthCenter);
    console.log("right", rightPos);

    if (rightPos > widthCenter)
      $(this).children(".menu").addClass("right").removeClass("left");
    else
      $(this).children(".menu").addClass("left").removeClass("right");

    var showingMenu = false;
    if ($(this).children(".menu").is(':visible'))
      showingMenu = true;
    $(".menu").hide();
    if (showingMenu)
      $(this).children(".menu").hide();
    else
      $(this).children(".menu").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 20px;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.left { left:0!important }
.right { right:0!important }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
  <span class="item">item<div class="menu"></div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Freedomn. Yes it makes sense now. I mistakenly thought that the left and right would override depending on the last applied. Cheers